# ASIHTTPRequest crashes if the response is late

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest in my app,my app crashes if it gets the response late or if the network is slow. for the time being I change the defaultTimeOut=100, earlier it was 10,so its working fine,is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you're not handling the error properly. You're not providing any code nor are you providing any crash logs, so I can't say what your doing wrong.

`ASIHTTPRequest` doesn't crash because of a late response, it produces an error. The fault lies with your error handling or perhaps lack of error handling.